# check if element of list is present in elements of another list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having some trouble with lists. So, basically, I have a list:

```
a=["Britney spears", "red dog", "\xa2xe3"]
```

and I have another list, looking like:

```
b = ["cat","dog","red dog is stupid", "good stuff \xa2xe3", "awesome Britney spears"]
```

what I would like to do is check if elements in `a` are part of some element in `b` - and if so, remove them from `b`'s element. So, I would like `b` to look like:

```
b = ["cat","dog","is stupid","good stuff","awesome"]
```

what is the most pythonic (in 2.7.x) way to achieve this?

I am assuming I can loop around to check each element, but I am not sure this is very efficient - I have a list (`b`) of around size 50k.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I'd use a regex here:

```
import re

a=["Britney spears", "red dog", "\xa2xe3"]

regex = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in a))

b=["cat","dog","red dog is stupid", "good stuff \xa2xe3", "awesome Britney spears"]

b = [regex.sub("",x) for x in b ]
print (b)  #['cat', 'dog', ' is stupid', 'good stuff ', 'awesome ']
```

This way, the regular expression engine can optimize the test for the list of alternatives.

Here are a bunch of alternatives to show how different regexs behave.

```
import re

a = ["Britney spears", "red dog", "\xa2xe3"]
b = ["cat","dog",
     "red dog is stupid", 
     "good stuff \xa2xe3", 
     "awesome Britney spears",
     "transferred dogcatcher"]

#This version leaves whitespace and will match between words.
regex = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in a))
c = [regex.sub("",x) for x in b ]
print (c) #['cat', 'dog', ' is stupid', 'good stuff ', 'awesome ', 'transfercatcher']

#This version strips whitespace from either end
# of the returned string
regex = re.compile('|'.join(r'\s*{}\s*'.format(re.escape(x)) for x in a))
c = [regex.sub("",x) for x in b ]
print (c) #['cat', 'dog', 'is stupid', 'good stuff', 'awesome', 'transfercatcher']

#This version will only match at word boundaries,
# but you lose the match with \xa2xe3 since it isn't a word
regex = re.compile('|'.join(r'\s*\b{}\b\s*'.format(re.escape(x)) for x in a))
c = [regex.sub("",x) for x in b ]
print (c) #['cat', 'dog', 'is stupid', 'good stuff \xa2xe3', 'awesome', 'transferred dogcatcher']


#This version finally seems to get it right.  It matches whitespace (or the start
# of the string) and then the "word" and then more whitespace (or the end of the 
# string).  It then replaces that match with nothing -- i.e. it removes the match 
# from the string.
regex = re.compile('|'.join(r'(?:\s+|^)'+re.escape(x)+r'(?:\s+|$)' for x in a))
c = [regex.sub("",x) for x in b ]
print (c) #['cat', 'dog', 'is stupid', 'good stuff', 'awesome', 'transferred dogcatcher']
```

Comment: Note the leading and trailing spaces.  He wants it trimmed in some, maybe all cases.  And he probably doesn't want extra spaces if the substring is chopped from the middle of a `b` element.

Comment: @sr2222 -- Maybe.  That's as easy as adding `.strip()` to the end of the `regex.sub`, or allowing the regular expressions to match whitespace around themselves -- `'|'.join(r'\s*{}\s*'.format(re.escape(x)) for x in a`

Comment: Maybe add some word-break protection?  Otherwise "red dog" would match "transferred dogcatcher" too.

Comment: @DSM -- Good suggestion -- Although as stated, it's not clear whether OP would *want* to transform that to `transfer catcher` or not ...

Comment: @mgilson: thank you for the awesome answer, Could you please explain what you mean by " the regular expression engine can optimize the test for the list of alternatives." how do I add word-break protection as DSM explains?

Comment: @JohnJ -- I don't know a lot about how regex engines work -- But, as you're the re engine and you're trying to match "foo","bar" or "baz", and you're walking through a string -- if the character you see is "q", you know that one isn't going to match anything so you really only have to look for "f" or "b".  Then if you find "b", you only need to look for "a" and so on ... In other words, you really only need to look at each character once to know if it matches something.  I'll add some other alternatives and their output.

Comment: @mgilson: thanks so much for the explanation - I have to admit, I am no expert in regex (quite poor I'd say)..I think Dominic's answer below also seems neat.. wonder which is a better one..

Comment: @JohnJ -- I'm going to promote mine -- His will transform `transferred dogcatcher` into `transfercatcher` no matter what you do  to it.  Also, I really believe that once your list of alternatives gets pretty big, `regex` will be more efficient (although you'd have to `timeit` to really know).

Comment: @mgilson: thanks again for such an awesome explanation - I get it now. I am going to use your method. Thanks again - could not have done this without your help!

Comment: I added an example that handles the `transferred dogcatcher` (using your regex :-)), and it seems to be faster than your approach. I think it's because it does some string checking before applying the regex and because the regex-patterns a created as needed, instead of creating one huge pattern that is applied every time. I'm sure one could (micro)-optimize this further by caching the compiled regex patterns :-)

Comment: @mgilson: what if b contained something like "good stuff\xa2xe3" (notice the no spaces).. in that case, does the following regex look good? regex = re.compile('|'.join(r'(?:|^)'+re.escape(x)+r'(?:\s+|$)' for x in a)) .. I deleted the \s+ which looks for a space in the beginning.. I am wondering if this is correct..

Comment: @JohnJ -- You're having conflicting rules here.  If you don't want to catch `red dog` in `transferred dog`, then it's hard to write a general rule where you will catch `\xa2xe3` in `good stuff\xa2xe3`.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @mgilson: yes, that makes sense.. I have no basically split all the "unicodes" into one bunch.. so I have something like a=["\xa2xa3","\xa9xf3","\xa2xs3"] and then b=["hello\xa2xa3", "welcome\xa2xs3"].. in this case..the above regex I have written seems to work if I take \s+ off both start and end of string. Does this look OK? :(

Comment: @mgilson: `\b`, maybe?  (That's what I was thinking of earlier, although I'm a regex antiexpert, so take that for what it's worth.)

Comment: @DSM -- I actually tried `\b` (see my 3rd regex).  The problem is that `\x...` doesn't seem to match there.

Comment: @mgilson: now I get you.  This exhausts my regex knowledge, so I'll just drop the mike ironically and leave the stage..

Comment: @DSM -- As I see it (from looking at the comments), OP actually wants to do this in 2 passes.  The first pass with what I have already, but without doing anything with the non-ascii strings.  The second pass which a slightly modified regex (`\s+` -> `\s*`) using the "unicode" strings.

Comment: @mgilson: yes, your right. Now, I am only bothered with "unicode" strings - since normal strings is easy enough (using your method).. for "unicodes only", I am using your second method.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't know if this counts as *pythonic* anymore, since `reduce` got exiled to `functools` in python3, someone has to put a one-liner on the table:

```
a = ["Britney spears", "red dog", "\xa2xe3"]
b = ["cat","dog","red dog is stupid", "good stuff \xa2xe3", "awesome Britney spears"]

b = [reduce(lambda acc, n: acc.replace(n, ''), a, x).strip() for x in b]
```

even faster would be

```
[reduce(lambda acc, n: acc.replace(n, '') if n in acc else acc, a, x).strip() for x in b]
```

but as readability decreases, it's getting less *pythonic* I think.

Here's one that handles the `transferred dogcatcher` case. I borrowed mgilson's regex, but I think it's OK because it's quite trivial :-):

```
def reducer(acc, n):
    if n in acc:
        return re.sub('(?:\s+|^)' + re.escape(n) + '(?:\s+|$)', '', acc)
    return acc

b = [reduce(reducer, a, x).strip() for x in b]
```

I extracted the `lambda` to a named function for readability.

Comment: At least `timeit` says so :-)

Comment: Yeah, I was using `timeit` on a simple test too.  It seems that `a in b` (where `a` isn't in `b`) is about 4x faster than `b.replace(a,'')` for the simple strings I was working with.  Of course, you end up going slower if `a` is almost always in `b`, but that's probably not OP's case.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the simplest would be a straight list comprehension, and as long as `a` is small, it even be a pretty efficient method.

```
b = [i for i in b if i not in a]
```

Comment: But this doesn't give you the "awesome" from "awesome Britney spears"

Comment: Oh, you actually want to remove `a` elements at a substring level, I didn't notice that.  Should the element of b be left empty or removed in the event that the whole thing gets filtered?